# Evaluating variable in T-SQL Case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm getting an

> Incorrect syntax near '='" for all '='

in the following CASE:

```
DECLARE @TipoRegisto    AS VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @idTipoRegisto  AS INT

SELECT 
       CASE @TipoRegisto            
              WHEN @idTipoRegisto = 0 THEN 'R' 
              WHEN @idTipoRegisto = 1 THEN 'I' 
              WHEN @idTipoRegisto = 2 THEN 'C' 
              ELSE  '' 
       END
```

Can anyone explain why, please?

Answer (score 1):

You were really close, Case returns the value that you want to set your variable to

```
DECLARE @TipoRegisto    AS VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @idTipoRegisto  AS INT

SELECT @TipoRegisto = CASE
                           WHEN @idTipoRegisto = 0 THEN 'R' 
                           WHEN @idTipoRegisto = 1 THEN 'I' 
                           WHEN @idTipoRegisto = 2 THEN 'C' 
                           ELSE  '' 
                      END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TipoRegisto    AS VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @idTipoRegisto  AS INT

SET @TipoRegisto = (SELECT 
                           CASE @idTipoRegisto            
                                WHEN 0 THEN 'R' 
                                WHEN 1 THEN 'I' 
                                WHEN 2 THEN 'C' 
                           ELSE  '' 
                     END)
```

Comment: Is that SELECT really necessary? Doesn't it worsen performance on the query when compared to the Cheruvian's answer?

Comment: It is not necessary for this... But if you check column value from table, that time you need it.

Comment: Another one, you are checking one variable, so you can use this simple case statement. (`CASE <var> WHEN <val1> THEN <v1>  WHEN <val2> THEN <v2> END` instead of `CASE WHEN <var> = <val1> THEN <v1>  WHEN <var> = <val2> THEN <v2> END`)